# External website data separate all H2 tags extracted

Tags: php, xpath

I am using the below to pull some data from an external website. Currently it is working and i am getting the data i need. The issue is i'm getting all h2 tags jumbled together. The below is what i am using:

```
  $no2_row = $no1_xpath->query('//div[3]/div/div/div/h2');
  if($no2_row->length > 0){
      foreach($no2_row as $row2){
        $name1 = $row2->nodeValue;
          echo $name1;
      }
```

Is there a way i can use `explode` or something so i can chose what i want to display? like `$name1_explode[5]` will show the 5th `H2` tag?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can:

```
$no2_row = $no1_xpath->query('//div[3]/div/div/div/h2[5]');
```

or

```
$no2_row = $no1_xpath->query('//div[3]/div/div/div/h2');
$data = array();
  if($no2_row->length > 0){
      foreach($no2_row as $row2){
        $data[] = $row2->nodeValue;
      }
}

echo $data[4];
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, your second recommendation that is. The only issue is it seems to be duplicating the correct answer. Before it was giving: 12345678 now it is giving 333333333